# How to sort by two values with same comparator

Tags: kotlin

I have two values that cannot be passed as var args:

```
sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, { it.lastName })
```

How can i add sorting by second field? I mean `it.lastName` and `it.firstName`.

**This is not duplicate as this is with using same comparator String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER**